# Creating Dynamic views based on ngRoute and a Restlike API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

I have set up a small HTML page with a ngView directive in it, which should update when any of the navigation links are clicked, after calling a Restlike API.  This bit seems to work, especially when there's no params to use in the request.

As soon as I try to add a param it fails with the following error:

```
 TypeError: undefined is not a function
at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/dashboard/js/factorys.js:11:16)
at Object.invoke (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.28/angular.js:3965:17)
at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.28/angular.js:3807:37
at getService (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.28/angular.js:3929:39)
at invoke (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.28/angular.js:3956:13)
at Object.instantiate (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.28/angular.js:3976:23)
at $get (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.28/angular.js:7315:28)
at link (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.28/angular-route.js:907:26)
at nodeLinkFn (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.28/angular.js:6752:13)
at compositeLinkFn (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.28/angular.js:6146:13) <div class="container ng-scope" ng-view="">
```

My angular scripts look like this:

controllers.js:

```
var dashboardControllers = angular.module('dashboardControl',['ngRoute','dashboardFactory']);
dashboardApp.controller('PlayersController', function ($scope, $routeParams, Player) {
    $scope.players = Player.findAll();
});
dashboardApp.controller('PlayerDetailsController', function ($scope, $routeParams, Player) {
    $scope.playerId = $routeParams.playerId;
    $scope.player = Player.get();
});
dashboardApp.controller('OverviewController', function ($scope, $routeParams, Overview) {
    $scope.overview = Overview.query();
});
```

factories.js:

```
var dashboardFactories = angular.module('dashboardFactory',['ngResource']);
dashboardFactories.factory("Overview", ['$resource',
    function ($resource) {
        return $resource('webresources/overview/', {}, {
            query: {method: 'GET', isArray: false}
        });
    }]);
dashboardFactories.factory("Player", ['$resource',
    function ($scope, $resource) {
        return $resource('webresources/player/:playerId', {}, {
            findAll: {method: 'GET', isArray: true},
            get: {method: 'GET', params: {playerId: $scope.playerId}, isArray: false}
        });
    }]);
```

The overview controller work, its the Player Controller I seem to be having the error message for.

Comment: You cannot inject $scope into factory via IoC. And also - your definition `dashboardFactories.factory("Player",` is wrong - one param $resource in the array is inejcted instead of the first argument *$scope* `function($scope, $resource)`

Comment: If I cant inject scope into the factory, how else could I get the playerId variable.

Comment: I do use UI-Router and almost forget how to work with ngroute... sorry for that. But the example and explanation I gave you in my answer should be clear and easily rewritable into older ngRoute... BTW - check UI-Router ;)

Comment: I didnt know there was another way to do this, was following a tutorial/adapting it to my requirements as I went, but got stuck here.  I'll check out UI-Router now, thanks.

Comment: UI-Router is just a tool for state machine. It is just replacement of the ngRoute... but the Resolve, controller, $resource... all that is the same... I just used different "background"... because I use to use it... Do you know what I mean? ... I suggest... check it. But to solve your current issue, it is not a must. I just used it for make the solution for you more simple...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created [working example here](http://plnkr.co/edit/J8FsGyXLNNbSqf7YkfWi?p=preview).

> *NOTE: It uses UI-Router instead of ngRoute... which I guess is really the right way... but the concept is exactly the same.*

Firstly we would define the resoruce "player":

```
.factory('player', ['$resource', function($resource){

   return $resource('player:playerId.json', {}, {
     findAll: {method: 'GET', isArray: true},
     get: {method: 'GET', isArray: false}
    });

}])
```

Why we used url like this **`player:playerId.json`**? Just because of the plunker. We profit here from the [parametrized URL template](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) ... which allows in the plunker have `player.json` for a list and `player + playerId +.json` for each player.

States definition:

```
// States
$stateProvider
  .state('list', {
      url: "/list",
      templateUrl: 'tpl.list.html',
      controller: 'PlayerListCtrl', 
      resolve : { 
        list : ['player', function(player){return player.findAll();}]
      }
  })
  .state('player', { 
      url: "/player/:playerId",
      templateUrl: 'tpl.player.html', 
      controller: 'PlayerCtrl', 
      resolve : { 
        player : ['player', '$stateParams'
        , function(player, $stateParams){
          return player.get({playerId: $stateParams.playerId});
        }]
      }
  })
```

The most important part is this:

```
player : ['player', '$stateParams'
, function(player, $stateParams){
  return player.get({playerId: $stateParams.playerId});
}]
```

Because we are letting angular to inject the `$stateParams` into our resolve. We then take the `playerId` parameter and pass that into **Templated URL** - so it will result in `player1.json`, `player2.json`,...

> In real life it would url like this 'server/api/resource/:id' - but the logic will be the same.

And these are consuming controllers:

```
.controller('PlayerListCtrl', ['$scope', 'list', function ($scope, list) {
  $scope.list = list;
}])
.controller('PlayerCtrl', ['$scope', 'player', function ($scope, player) {
  $scope.player = player;
}])
```

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/J8FsGyXLNNbSqf7YkfWi?p=preview)